# Check if a Facebook user likes a specific page and display content

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've searched all over the Internet and tried different ways to check if an user likes
a specific page but I haven't get it done.
My code is from here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/X4bn6/1042/
I think the problem is with my app. It returns me a wrong user ID (different from that generated by: http://graph.facebook.com/username)
My app website and domains are correctly filled.

Anyone know what could be the problem? Or have a solution which doesn't need a facebook app?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: _“I think the problem is with my app. It returns me a wrong user ID”_ – no, the problem is that you completely neglected to inform yourself about the changes API v2.0 introduced.

Comment: You're right! it returns me the 'new' app scoped user id. I've requested for extended permission (user_likes) and they've replied me that my app doesn't need it.

Comment: You will not get `user_likes` approved for the purpose of like gating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to check, are you asking for user_likes permissions?

Second, you can replace your FQL by:

```
var fql_query = "SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id = "+page_id+" AND uid= me()";
```

I hope it helps.

Cheers,

Comment: I've sent again a user_likes request and I hope this time will get approved. I don't want to use FQL anymore. They've mentioned that at the following update this wouldn't work anymore. Now, my question is: The following code will work with the app scoped user id or still I need the original user id ?
FB.api(
    "/{user-id}/likes/{page-id}",
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        /* handle the result */
      }
    }
);

Comment: Using the Graph API you'll use: https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes
You must pass the access token too.